# Solidworks freezes when creating an angle mate

Tags: solidworks

When I try to create an angle mate in an assembly by pressing shift and choosing the angle option in the menu that appears, a green and white mouse appears next to the arrow and I cannot access any other options or set the angle. What key should be pressed to set the angle?

[image]

Comment: You probably need to add a few more details for this. Version and Service pack, which entities have you selected before pressing the commands. It might be just a bug.

Comment: Yeah, this is going to need a .gif or screen recording to diagnose I think...